# Angular how do I implement mutually exclusive checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

```
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="coordinatorSearch" id="coordinatorSearch" formControlName="coordinatorFilter" (click)="validateOption($event)"/>
            <label for="coordinatorSearch">Coordinator</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="employeeSearch" id="employeeSearch" formControlName="employeeFilter" (click)="validateOption($event)"/>
            <label for="employeeSearch">Employee</label>
        </div>
```

How do I make these checkboxes mutually exclusive? If the user clicks the 'employeeSearch' to the on poistion then we toggle the 'coordinatorSearch' off (if it had been on)

I just don't want two switches turned on but both can be turned off.

Comment: Watch for changes in those two fields with `formControl.valueChanges` and if either of them is set to On, set the other one to Off

Comment: What about radiobutton?

Comment: From the UX standpoint this sounds like this should be radio element instead of a checkbox. You can still style it as a checkbox if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually went to radio buttons. It was very hard to make a checkbox to behave like a radio.